# Chrome doesn't render any images in the first click

Tags: model-view-controller

I am rendering a lot of link images (images made as link) and making them all in [color box](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/).
Each link is to a controller method that returns corresponding FilePathResult.
All the browsers renders image on the color box on clicking  the link.
But chrome don’t render any image in the first click later on it renders image.
Any clues?

Comment: Why is this tagged `mvc`? Did you mean `asp.net-mvc`?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but do the filenames of these images you say that aren't being rendered contain the word '*ad*' or '*ads*'? Or do the parent elements contain these words in their attribute values?

I know Chrome does not render ads by default by looking at attribute names or filenames. So if your filenames / attributes contain this word in some way, rename them.

Comment: Words 'ad' or 'ads' is not there.